# Crash on CreateConnection SQL CE

Tags: entity-framework

Hi we have a product of a C# WPF application riding upon a C++ engine.

Occasionally (more often than we would like) we have to debug the whole stack.

Recently I started having a crash occur in the application on the creation of a connection.

> connection = Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(connectionString);

yes I have tried creating a connection by this method.  But it produces the same error.

> var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
>   connection = factory.CreateConnection();
>   connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

We have a SQL CE database for storing...well data.
We access it using EF Code First.
We found in the past we could improve performance by creating ONE connection (it is one file) and reusing the connection.

The app is crashing on me WHEN it creates the connection NOT our code.
I have tried catching Exception or ExecutionEnginException (I could not find FatalExecutionEngineException)

I have also tried reinstalling the various packages related to our EF stack.
All to no avail.

Please help if you have run into this problem or a MS engineer that scours the stackoverflow boards.

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in > >'(our application)'.
>
> Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the  error was at 0xd8ed0f68, on thread 0x2330. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Do you dispose all the disposable objects?

Comment: It occurs on startup.

Comment: 0xc0000005 indicates a acces violation. It ocurs when trying to write to a memory adres outside the bounds of the application. This usually indicates a problem in native code. How are you using the c++ engine you mentioned?

Comment: I know that it is access violation.  The C++ engine is used for image processing and device communication.  It (C++ engine) really has not been started yet so it can't be the source of the problem.   I also made it go away by unchecking the Native Debugging in the Debug tab.  The compiled release version and debug of only C# code work fine.